# How to manage SPFx source code

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, modern-team-site

I'm developing SPFx with team members and I'm thinking about how to manage the source code.
What do you use to manage your source code?
What services can I use to manage the SPFx source code?
I would appreciate with any idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could upload your source code to [github](https://github.com/). It's a great platform to host your code